# How to read special objects from richtextbox and store it in Access?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, ms-word, richtextbox

I have one requirement where i need to get mathematical expressions from user for which they use Microsoft Equation Editor and paste it in application `inputbox(Rich textbox)` and store it in Access Database. Later on i need to generate a report in Office Word doc by reading the data. I Read the data from richtextbox as `byte[]` but it reads only the normal text not the mathematical expressions.

Comment: What version of Word are you using? Microsoft Equation Editor is somewhat obsolete. Do the equations display correctly in the rich textbox? Are you moving the equations into Access using databound controls? What types are you using for all these intermediate steps?

Comment: thanks nicholas,I am using  Word 2007, yes it displays correctly, i converted the text in the richtextbox into byte array and store it into access db as OLEobject. it stores all the text except the mathematical expressions.